# Simplesamlphp interface not Loading

Tags: linux, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I have installed Simplesamlphp on ubuntu server and it all goes well with the installation, but when I try to access it from the browser its not loading front page or login page it just shows me the code.

```php
<?php

require_once('_include.php';

$config = \SimpleSAML\Configuration::getInstance();

if ($config->getBoolean('usenewui', false)) {
    \SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP::redirectTrustedURL(SimpleSAML\Module::getModuleURL('core/login'));
}

\SimpleSAML\Utils\HTTP::redirectTrustedURL(SimpleSAML\Module::getModuleURL('core/frontpage_welcome.php'));
```

Any ideas?

I have tried several solutions but didn't work.